# Drive SDK Configuration issues

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Hello friends i want to use drive api with signed apk so i follow all steps and also configure drive sdk  so below is my images

This is my images which i setting done in my 
[image: App_ICON]

[image: Image_2]
[image: Image_3]
Above is my setting when i click on save change it give me error like **Your input was invalid.** any idea which way i make wrong ?

Comment: You are not getting any prompts for other sections when you see "Your Input was Invalid"? Try using only a single image, as that works for me when I try and replicate your settings. Also, you should black out or hide your clientID.

Comment: @Andy:  Ya it is working !!